# Docker container STDOUT not showing in Docker Logs

Tags: linux, docker, logging, stdout, docker-logs

I am trying to configure my php errors to output to docker logs. All documentation I have read indicates that docker logs are tied to the containers stdout and stderr which come from /proc/self/fd/1 and /proc/self/fd/2. I created a symlink from my php error log file /var/log/php_errors.log to /proc/self/fd/1 with command:

```
ln -sf /proc/self/fd/1 /var/log/php_errors.log
```

After linking the error log I have tested its functionality by running this php script:

```
<?php
 error_log("This is a custom error message constructed to test the php error logging functionality of this site.\n"); 
?>
```

The output echos the error message to the console so I can see that php error logging is now redirected to stdout in the container, but when I run `docker logs -f <containername>` I never see the error message in the logs. Also echoing from inside the container doesn't show in the logs either which is confusing because my understanding is the echo command is stdout.

Further reading informed me that docker logs will only show output from pid 1 which could be the issue. If this is the case how can I correctly configure my php error logging to show in docker logs outside the container.

Also I have checked that I am using the default json-file docker driver, and have tried this both on my local environment and a web server.